# Prime Numbers...

Tags: computational-mathematics

Are there any functions whose output is a prime number?
For eg. The function $x^2$ spits out squares of $x$; is there a similar function for ***Prime Numbers*** as well(which gives output as Prime Numbers)?

Comment: Well, you could consider this a troll answer, but on fancier calculators there is often a function called $\text{NextPrime}(x)$ which returns the smallest prime that is larger than $x$ ...

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes

Answer (score 0):

A function is, *in essence*, is a well-defined rule.

Do prime numbers follow a well-defined rule? *No.*

So, there can't be a function whose output is a prime number , atleast not one which can be written out **algebraically** ( you could *define* a function however; for example you can define a function f(n) = n iff Φ(n) = n-1 and so on. Φ(N) here denotes the totient function)

You can have a function which gives primes for atleast some values of n algebraically ( i.e. with a restricted domain )
e.g. p(n) = ${n^2+n+41}$
which gives primes for inputs upto 39, but fails at 40.

Edit 1: By algebraically, I mean not by using simple/elementary operations, i.e. not in the form of a polynomial.

Edit 2: By algebraically, I mean not by using simple/elementary operations, i.e. not in the form of a **finite** polynomial.

Comment: Well I am not so sure about it...... sine can be represented as a polynomial

Comment: Also I am not so sure prime numbers do not follow any rule...................Please send any proof if you have that they do not........

Comment: @Aatmaj fixed that... Changed it to a finite polynomial

Comment: OP was comparing it with $ {x^2}$, so I am only saying that you can't have a similarly (finite) polynomial that ''spits out'' primes.

Answer (score 0):

A simple function is

${\displaystyle f(n)=\left\lfloor {\frac {n!{\bmod {(}}n+1)}{n}}\right\rfloor (n-1)+2}$

(for positive integer n, where ${\displaystyle \lfloor \ \rfloor }$ is the floor function, which rounds down to the nearest integer.)

Proof-By Wilson's theorem, +1 is prime if and only if ${\displaystyle n!\equiv n{\pmod {n+1}}}$. Thus, when n+1 is prime, the first factor in the product becomes one, and the formula produces the prime number n+1. But when n+1 is not prime, the first factor becomes zero and the formula produces the prime number 2.

Comment: This formula is not an efficient way to generate prime numbers because evaluating ${\displaystyle n!{\bmod {(}}n+1)}$ requires about n-1 multiplications and reductions ${\displaystyle {\bmod {(}}n+1)}.$

Comment: Everybody can copy-paste Wikipedia. You could have just provided the link.

Comment: @Forester thanks for the suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Conway's prime algortihm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) ([see also](https://oeis.org/wiki/Conway%27s_PRIMEGAME)) finds all primes using a "simple" rule if I am not mistaken.